# Reference to parent form from Class Library

Tags: c#, forms, reference, class-library

I've been trying to compile all my classes into a class library which is a really nice feature.  My goal is to have all my code in there that doesn't include the code for a specific application.  When I try to add a class that references the parent form I run into issues because there is no parent form in the class library.  How do I create a reference to a form that it yet unknown until the parent class is created in the application?

```
public class Form1 : Form
{

private Child child;

public Form1()
{
    child = new Child(this);
}


}


public class Child
{


    private Form1 parent;
    public Child(Form1 parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }


}
```

This code works in a standard application, but when I add the Child class to the class library, the "Form1" text will not compile because Form1 is not included in the class library.  Is there any way around this?  Thank you for any help.

Comment: If `Child` is to be placed in a library then it should not have any dependencies on Form1

Comment: As I commented on the other answer.  Is it best practice to have then made an event in the child and subscribe to it from the parent rather than calling a method on the parent from the child?  Thanks.

Comment: Use events to break the dependency on the view.  Use an interface if that causes hardship.

Answer (score 1):

As `Form1` derives from `Form`, why not take `Form` as a parameter to the constructor of `Child`?

```
public class Child
{
    private Form parent;
    public Child(Form parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

This will at least break the dependency on your application from your class library, but it will still require a dependency on WinForms for `Form`. It depends on what you intend to do with `parent` in your code though as to whether this is sufficient.

Comment: I tried this and realized that it will not work because my child form is calling a function on the parent form.  I'm self taught but I'm starting to think this is bad practice due to the dependency issue.  Would the correct and better way be creating an event on the child form and subscribing to it on the parent form.  Then when the event is triggered it would call that function on the parent form?  Thank you.

Comment: Yes events would definitely be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
Parent.FindForm()
```